# Redirect if page has already been visited

Tags: php, javascript

I think I'm stuck and I really hope someone can help me out here.
So, I'm trying to make something like a quiz application with PHP and JS. The idea is that the user is given a picture with 4 possible answers and he has to guess what's in that picture. User receives x points based on the answer he clicked and gets redirected to the next page, with picture and answers, and so on. There's also a chance for user to skip to the next page. Here's the thing though:

How do I check if the user has already answered particular question, so I could redirect him to the next page if this one has already been answered? Basically, it would be like a protection from cheating, so that the user couldn't get more and more points from the same question.
I'm currently stuck with MySQL solution, to make column for every page, store values there and then compare them when user tries to access particular page, redirecting him based on the stored value. Is it the only solution?
I'm sorry if my english isn't that good, and I hope you guys can understand my question. :)

Comment: Have you tried using $_SESSION variables?

Comment: Yeah, I tried setting a $_SESSION variable and it worked for a while. But, when I logged out and then logged back in, I was able to access the first question again.

Comment: If you want to save permanently answered questions for one user, you have to store them in some kind of permanent storage. Most frequently used is MySQL database.

Comment: You're already using the best solution, it seems to me. The only SURE way to know if a user has answered a particular question is to keep track in the database. ANY client-side solution (including cookies and session variables) is subject to possible tampering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned, that user can log in and log out. Therefore I presume, that you already have a database of users and you want to store somehow which questions were already answered by particular user, but you don't know, what's the proper way of storing such information into MySQL database.

Now, I am sorry if I got wrong, what you meant, but if my assumptions are correct, then there are several ways, how to store the data you want to save. You can for example add another column to the table with users, that will contain the last question that the user answered. And you can update that value everytime user answers next question.

So i.e. if you had 4 questions, the column would be empty. When you come to the page with question, you look into database, what's the last question this user answered. Since this user didn't answer any question thus the column is still empty, you can ask him the first question. If he answers, you can update now the column with value 1. Next time the same user accesses page with questions, you look again into database into the very same column and you will get value 1. So now you now, you've already asked first question and you can ask the user the next question.

In case questions are not asked in specific order and can be presented randomly, you have other possible solution: Create a reference table. You can create new table, which will contain three columns: user_id, question_id and answer to that question(if you need to save the answer too). Now everytime user opens the page that generates questions, you can look into your table with questions and select all those questions, that are not answered by the user. So you do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM questions_table 
WHERE question_id NOT IN 
(SELECT question_id 
FROM questions_answered_by_users 
WHERE user_id=$currentUserId)
```

Comment: Well, my questions are presented pretty much randomly. I was thinking about making another table to store values for comparison, but I really hoped that I wouldn't need to go down that road, because I'm still pretty new to databases and didn't really know what kind of relation I need between tables. I came up with solution - make one-to-one relation with comparison table and get values from there, but I ended up with table which had more than 20 columns (for each question), honestly, that made me think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: yes because the way to do it is NOT to create column for EVERY page, rather user REFERENCE table (as explained in my anwer). You'll have a table, where you will have stored your questions. Every question must have a unique ID. Now everytime the user answers the question, you just store the answer in separate table, that MUST have two columns: user_id and question_id -> as explained in my answer along with SQL how to then select for every user a questions that he did not answer

Comment: Ok, thank's! Didn't know what kind of tables I should use, so, your post really helped me. I will try to get more information about using reference tables. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This SO answer might help you understand the problem better:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/how-do-i-create-a-cross-reference-table-query-for-my-data

Answer (score 0):

Store a unique value for each question into a session variable. If that session variable exists then redirect to the next page.

```
// init.php
session_start();


// question1.php
require 'init.php';
if (isset($_SESSION['question1'])
    header('location: http://mysite.com/question2.php');
else
    $_SESSION['question1'] = TRUE;

// put the question code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use MySQL db so its a permanent solution but you dont need to make new column for every page.
you can just have 1 column and the row data to be a JSON object that you could keep on referring to it

```
{page1:'done'}
```

then when you are going to save it could look like this

```
{page1:'done',page2:'done'}
```

You can use json_encode and json_decode php functions for this one.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to look into this one.

Comment: this is partly how mongoDB works. Will send you some more links/codes when we land later, we're traveling in airplane now.

Comment: I strongly discourage using this solution. It's better to use reference tables, because those can be indexed easily and perform well even in case your page will have hundreds of thousands of users. While solution suggested in this answer will work, it's profoundly more heavy on performance and it's also some kind of hindrance to do json_encode and json_decode everytime you want to store some data to database. Reference tables are really the way, that tasks as yours are dealt with

Comment: Sure, there are other solutions too. You can create rows, indexes on tables if he wants. but I think he just need to simplify his approach for this one as its only about the been "visited".

Answer (score 0):

A permanent solution and I believe the only one is some sort of database (mysql, xml, file, etc) server-side.
Another way but can be cheated is a cookie, create a json with json_encode with which pages had been visited and save them in a cookie valid for 30 days. Although this can be cheated by deleting the cookies or opening a different browser.