# View video once and redirect to another website

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, video

I have been assigned with task of only allowing a video to be viewed once using WordPress website and after being watch once and the video end, have the website URL redirect to another page. The video does not play but still redirect after 1 minutes.

Here is my code

```
[videojs_video url="http://tecfa.unige.ch/guides/html/html5-video/videos/state-of-wikipedia-480x272.mp4" preload="auto" controls ="false" autoplay = "true" loop="true"]
    <script>
         setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.href = 'https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/';
         }, 60000);
      </script>
      <p>Web page redirects after 1 minute.</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ended` event to detect if the video has finished playing:

```js
let myVideo = document.getElementById('my-video');

myVideo.addEventListener('ended', videoCompleted, false);

function videoCompleted(e) {
  console.log('video has completed');
  window.location.href = 'https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/';
}
```

```html
<video controls src="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_640_3MG.mp4" id="my-video"></video>
```

Comment: How to I prevent my user from going back to the same video site after redirect to another url?

Comment: It's probably worth asking that as a separate question, and it depends on how secure you need it to be. You could write a session variable once the video has been watched, and then check it before loading the page. But your users could get around that by clearing their browser cache.

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314218/redirect-if-page-has-already-been-visited shows you how you'd do it with PHP, which might be a better option here

Comment: I have figure out how to disable the go back to previous page. Thanks for your code. it truly help a lot