# Join on column which can have multiple entries SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables.  One has entries like:

```
User_ID     Cat_ID

1           [1,2]
2           [1]
3           [3]
```

And in the other I have strings associated with the category IDs:

```
Cat_ID      Cat_Name
1           Category1
2           Category2
3           Category3
```

I want to be able to perform a join on the CatID so I get something like:

```
User_ID    Category_ID
1          ['Category1', 'Category2']   
2          ['Category1']
3          ['Category3']
```

I understand about joins on columns if that column has only single entries to allow for one to one mapping, but how can I do many one to one mappings for the same column?

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Like jarlh said. There's no simple solution to your question. You should change your DB design to have a many-to-many relationship table between user and cat, with rows like `usr_id=1 cat_id=1 | usr_id=1 cat_id=2`

Comment: If you can change the database I would recommend adding a [cross-reference table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/how-do-i-create-a-cross-reference-table-query-for-my-data) between User and Category.  This will solve today's problem, and many, many more to come.  If you cannot; search this site for questions on [splitting strings](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+split+string).

Comment: Hi thanks for your comments.  This was unfortunately an inherited problem so I am trying to salvage what I can!

Comment: My other idea was to split the Cat_ID entry and have a separate columns for each number, which could be updated as True/False if present, and then try and combined with CASE statements to get the correct series of names.
Something like:

    User_ID | cat_1 | cat_2| cat_3...
         1            1          1         0

Comment: Multiple columns are a real pain to work with.  Imagine you want to find each employee with cats 2 & 3.  You'll have to check two columns instead of one.  And then what happens when someone is assigned a third cat?  You'll be forced to add yet another column, and you'll have to update all your existing queries.

Comment: I missed read your comment.  Separating the cats in a series of bit fields could work; if the list is relatively small and does not change very often.  One downside to this approach is without a cat table you'll have nowhere to store attributes belonging to each cat (name, higher level groups, etc).

Comment: hi @JoeyCrossy  can  u check my answer

Answer (score 0):

For splitting of values in to columns we need to create function

```
create function [dbo].[udf_splitstring] (@tokens    varchar(max),
                                             @delimiter varchar(5))
    returns @split table (
      token varchar(200) not null )
    as
      begin
          declare @list xml

          select @list = cast('<a>'
                              + replace(@tokens, @delimiter, '</a><a>')
                              + '</a>' as xml)

          insert into @split
                      (token)
          select ltrim(t.value('.', 'varchar(200)')) as data
          from   @list.nodes('/a') as x(t)

          return
      end


    create table #a
    (
        User_ID int,     Cat_ID varchar(10)
    )
    insert into #a values
    (1,'1,2'),
    (2,'1'),
    (3,'3')


    create table #b
    (
        Cat_ID int,      Cat_Name varchar(50)
    )
    insert into #b values

    (1,'Category1'),
    (2,'Category2'),
    (3,'Category3')



    ;WITH CTE AS
    (
    SELECT USER_ID,B.CAT_NAME FROM (SELECT T.USER_ID,CAST(X.TOKEN AS INT) AS CAT_ID 
        FROM #A T
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOKEN FROM [UDF_SPLITSTRING](T.CAT_ID,',') ) X)C
        JOIN (SELECT * FROM #B) B ON B.CAT_ID=C.CAT_ID
        )

        SELECT  USER_ID
           ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(CAT_NAME AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
             FROM cte 
             WHERE USER_ID = t.USER_ID
             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
            .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') Category_ID
    FROM cte t
    GROUP BY USER_ID

USER_ID  Category_ID
1        Category1, Category2
2        Category1
3        Category3
```