# Check First on Table A, if not found Check on other table

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a Log in and I have separate tables for Users A and Users B.

What I want to do is check first in first table if the Users that trying to Login is in the Table A, 
**if YES**, it will not go to the Table B to check the Login credentials, **if NOT**, go to Table B and check the Login credentials.

**Table A**

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE userId='$userId' AND password='$password'
```

**Table B**

```
SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE accountNumber='$accountNumber' AND password='$password'
```

**Note:** The 2 Tables has different Field Name `userId` and `accountNumber`.

Comment: Do the tables have the same structure?

Comment: Why you can't check the number of results returned ?

Comment: Somme thing like? 
SELECT * FROM tableA, tableB WHERE userId='$userId' AND password='$password' OR accountNumber='$accountNumber' AND password='$password'

Comment: @Mureinik, they are not the same.

Comment: @bhansa, sorry, can you please elaborate? I don't undertand, I am still a newbie.

Comment: @user3633383 I dont know if it will work but I will try.

Comment: May have to prefix the table name for it too work: SELECT * FROM tableA, tableB WHERE tableA.userId='$userId' AND tableA.password='$password' OR tableB.accountNumber='$accountNumber' AND tableB.password='$password'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you are fetching the values of username and password from client side so I will tell you only what you asked for.

```
   $getUserBasic1=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE userId="$userId" AND password="$password"');

$getUserBasic1->execute();
$user= $getUserBasic1->fetchAll();
if(count($user)>0)
{
//if yes do what you want here
}
else
{
$getUserBasic2=$db2->prepare('SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE accountNumber="$accountNumber" AND password="$password"');
$getUserBasic2->execute();
$user2= $getUserBasic2->fetchAll();
//write your code here
}
```

Comment: I will mark this an answer because I think this is what I am looking for. But others answer is also good in other way.

Comment: SQL is faster than PHP, you limit the potential of your application scale. It would be more efficient and manageable to create a model to retrieve this data and then allow controllers to access it rather than PHP Logic to gather the data. It works if you're looking to scale your application on a small and you are not fussed about future builds and speed however, for 'better practice' I suggest not using this as the accepted answer.

Comment: KDOT you need to understand difference between PDO and MVC dude.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [`INNER JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) and select both table results taking Table A's result first if it exists, else take Table B's result.

Assuming both tables have some sort of reference like the User ID you can use something like this:

```
SELECT tbla.*, tblb.* FROM tableA tbla 
INNER JOIN tableB tblb ON tbla.userId = tblb.userId
WHERE userId='$userId' OR accountNumber='$accountNumber' AND password='$password'
ORDER BY userId ASC
LIMIT 1
```

The query above uses the [cross-reference (userId in this case)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/how-do-i-create-a-cross-reference-table-query-for-my-data) and joins both tables together before querying the results. It orders the results by Table A before Table B but limits the result to 1 bringing either Table A or Table B out depending which is null.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, however both table has different field. `userId` is not available in `tableB` and `accountNumber` is not available in `tableA`. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You should create a cross reference in the tables then, allowing this to work. Ie, create some sort of table that is unique to the user that can be cross referenced. INNER JOIN is efficient because the data in the tables can be dynamically mapped allowing for large scaled applications

Comment: Thanks for the tips, so your answer is better in large applications that the answer I accepted? So for the future, I'd know what kind of good and not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try combining the tables, some thing like:

```
 SELECT * FROM tableA, tableB WHERE tableA.userId='$userId' AND tableA.password='$password' OR tableB.accountNumber='$accountNumber' AND tableB.password='$password'
```

I have not checked, so may not work, but see if this gets what you are looking for!

Comment: well the result of the query is not right. I don't know why it displaying all the fields of table A even though the userId and password is not in other rows of the table.

Comment: Because you're also selecting everything from Table B so some rows will be empty, that won't matter since they will be ignored in your PHP logic @Marksmanship

Comment: @KDOT, ah I see. I tested it in my codes and well it works, these answer. By the way, I didn't try yet your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$sql = "SQL QUERY FOR TABLEA";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // checking if result in TABLE A 
    }
else{
    //search in TABLE B by updating your sql value.
}
```

I hope that you want to check for the **registered** user, the best way to do that is to keep one table and just search there itself keeping the **userID** as the primary key.